# Seeking good IM/chat modules

Tags: 7

My users are asking for "chat", but I suspect they mean one on one IM rather than multi-uer chat rooms.

If there is no negative interaction, I could offer both.

There seem to be a few available, so I will just install them all and try them out one by one, unless someone can make a recommendation.

I need something stable for Drupal 7, easy to use for non-sophisticated users (although they all use IM & FB and the like).

We have Organic Groups so anything that can leverage that somehow might be a bonus.

---

Update: I am *not* asking what is "best". I am asking what is stable, well supported, easy to install and administer and easy for unsophisticated users. I ought to have made that clearer before. I just want to cut down my search list.

---

Review: Drupal Chat has [a live demo](http://drupalchat.botskool.co.in/node/1), so try it out.

There is a small grey box labelled "Chat" permanently at the bottom of the screen, showing the number of on-line users. Clicking reveals a list of users, clicking one begins chat (whether the other user likes it or not).

Options are currently in progress (i.e. none).

User is not informed when partner disconnects and just keeps typing, getting no reply. "go idle/go online" has no effect.

User can chat, but that 's all. Still very much a work in progress as at Nov 2011.

Comment: This question is rather subjective: What is good for you, is not good for somebody else.

Comment: I agree. But I am not really asking what is best for me (when I ask questions like that I always qualify what is "me". Then the question "what is best for x,y,z" is not subjective). In this case I am just asking what is stable and well supported. I will make the question clearer.

Comment: It is subjective, as who answer to any "What is a good […]?" question answer basing what is good for themselves, not what is good for you. If you indeed describe what your requirements are, then the answerers can better answer you, especially if the requirements restrict the possible candidates to one or two modules.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Well, users are generally in their 20s (and I am *ahem* not). They are fairly inarticulate and just shrug and say "you know..." when asked. So, I guess I am trying to copy FaceBook or Google Chat or the like - none of which I use, which makes it tough. The closest I got to help was one saying that if they see someone is online they would like to chat, so I guess some sort of IM ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also check this out: http://www.cometchat.com/

Its not free but its cheap and looks good. Also it integrates with drupal.

Comment: +1 (and the answer) Thanks. Although I always prefer free this one is so good that I am seriously considering it. Even paying out of my own pocket it is well worth it. The $49 10 chat version looks like a good trial. I wonder if they have an upgrade path to the $129 ... video chat & IM, worked on shared servers, integrates with Gchat & FB ...a nd on and on ... thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Drupal Chat](http://drupal.org/project/drupalchat) module for chat. It uses node.js and hence highly scalable

> - Supports smileys (detects them automatically in chat messages)
> - Chat history is retained in between page loads
> - Provides option to use Normal AJAX, long polling and Node.js (only in 7.x) techniques to update chat messages
> - Provides optional integration with User Relationships module.

Comment: Sorry, I won't be using it unless there is no alternative. Please see me review above. Thanks for helping, though :-)

Answer (score 2):

[DrupalChat](http://drupal.org/project/drupalchat) module has improved significantly now. It's cloud hosted commercial version is highly stable, extremely easy-to-use (as suggested in question) and offers both private (one-to-one) chat and multiple chat rooms. You may view live [demo here](https://iflychat.com).

Answer (score 2):

You can try http://drupal.org/project/googlechat.

This module comes with following features

- multiple theme (base, blitzer, Cupertino, dark-hive and famous Google hangout).
- bottom right display of chat boxes.
- Auto-back-off polling policy
- Auto-scrolling of chat text and more

Detailed documentation is available at http://www.nextweblink.com/2015/02/18/google-style-jquery-chat-drupal/

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Chat Room](http://drupal.org/project/chatroom) module. It supports private chats.

Comment: I installed it, can't get it to work and now I can't disable it in /admin/modules

Comment: The installation is described in _README.txt_ file of the module. You need to configure it a little bit. If You would like to disable the extension in admin interface, but somehow it doesn't work, You could try to do it with _drush_, with _pm-disable_ key.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I think that I have installed & configured it, but cannot find in the docs how to use it (or did I miss something?). How do I get the user to access it? Do I need to add a view or menu item or something?   The page  /chatroomread.php  just 'hangs' or shows blank ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://www.drupal.org/project/chatroom. Hopefully, it covers your requirements. Most ot the other modules I have search are very expensive.